# POST and GET with Grunt ( GruntFile.js )

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, yeoman

as you'll probably notice, I'am new to YEOMAN and GRUNT.
I have recently installed "yeoman angular generator" and I'am having trouble passing data between the grunt server ( gruntfile.js ) and web pages ( index.html ).
I'am trying to do something like POST and GET like express ( node.js ) does.
Basically all I want to do is to send some variables from client side ( HTML ) to server ( Grunt ) and to be able to recieve data ( variables , JSON, HTML )

The Angular Generator : https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

The gruntfile.js : http://www.filetolink.com/293e57448f

Comment: Try this to get basics buddy.. [https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-http]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the `yeoman angular generator` only create a simple static website with no server side ability.

If you want to fetch informations you can:

- Put static JSON files in the web directory. (If you don't need server side processing)
- Build you a little server

For the second solution you can continue to use `yeoman` if you like. There is a few generator for it like this one: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-express